# Getting a dataframe from a dictionary of dictionaries

Tags: pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a resulting_dictionary with these keys and values:

```
{"A":{"z1":[1,2,3],"z2":[3,2,2],"z3":"mary"},
"B":{"z1":[4,4,3],"z2":[2,1,1],"z3":"john","z4":[6,5,4],"z5":[2,2,2]}}
```

I am looking forward to turn it to a df to look like this:

```
    z1    z2    z3    z4     z5
A   1     3     mary   nan   nan
A   2     2     mary   nan   nan
A   3     2     mary   nan   nan
B   4     2     john    6     2
B   4     1     john    5     2
B   3     1     john    4     2
```

This is my code:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(resulting_dictionary, orient='index').reset_index() 

    lst_col=list(df.columns)
    empty_df=pd.DataFrame()
    for nums in lst_col:
        try:
            res = pd.DataFrame({
                col: np.repeat(df[col].values, df[nums].str.len())
                for col in df.columns.drop(nums)}).assign(
                **{nums: np.concatenate(df[nums].values)})[df.columns]

        except TypeError:
            empty_df[nums] = [None] * 6

        empty_df['index'] = res['index']
        empty_df['z3'] = res['z3']
        empty_df[nums] = res[nums]
    print(empty_df)
```

I have tried some code but I think I am extending myself very much to reach to the desired output.
Any alternative way to easily get the df from the resulting_dictionary?

Comment: I think you are looking for the pandas explode function. See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html

Comment: I was using the alternative to pandas explode in the code (considering I am using v 0.23.4)

Comment: Is the shape of `resulting_dictionary` always the same?

Comment: @jorijnsmit  No, it depends on the subkeys that might be found under A,B or whatever key. What will always be the same is the length of the list values among the subkeys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {"A":{"z1":[1,2,3],"z2":[3,2,2],"z3":"mary"},
"B":{"z1":[4,4,3],"z2":[2,1,1],"z3":"john","z4":[6,5,4],"z5":[2,2,2]}}

final_df = pd.DataFrame()
for i,j in data.items():
  q = pd.concat({k: pd.Series(v) for k, v in j.items()}, axis=1)
  q.index=np.repeat(i,len(j[list(j.keys())[0]]))
  q.groupby("z3").ffill()
  q['z3'] = q['z3'].ffill()
  final_df= pd.concat([final_df, q])
```

**Output:**

```
    z1  z2  z3  z4  z5
A   1   3   mary    NaN NaN
A   2   2   mary    NaN NaN
A   3   2   mary    NaN NaN
B   4   2   john    6.0 2.0
B   4   1   john    5.0 2.0
B   3   1   john    4.0 2.0
```